# How to get a randomised distribution of div elements using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to position my elements randomly throughout a particular container, the elements are generated using javascript, i have also added styling directly using javascript but instead of getting the elements into random points as expected they all appear on one line.

Here is the html am working with, it doesnt have much:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/script.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="animation-container">
        <div class="box">
            
        </div>
        <button class="button">click me</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the css am working with

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.animation-container{
    border: 2px solid black;

    width: 70vw;
    height: 70vh;

    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    
    align-items: center;

    /* overflow: hidden; */

    
}
```

And here is the main javascript file that does the heavy lifting

```
const backgroundColor = document.querySelector('.box')


function createDiv(){
    for(i=0;i<=60;i++){
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div')
        newdiv.classList = `name${i}`
        // const newproduct = document.querySelector(`.name${i}`)

        const percentage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        const distance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)
        const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        const c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)

        const d = Math.random().toFixed(1)
        


        newdiv.style.right = `${percentage}%`
        newdiv.style.borderRadius = '50%'
        newdiv.style.bottom = `${percentage}%`
        newdiv.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${a},${b},${c},${d})`;
        newdiv.style.width = `${distance}px`
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute'
        newdiv.style.height = `${distance}px`

        backgroundColor.append(newdiv)
        console.log(newdiv)
    }
}

createDiv()
```

here is the jsfeedle to see the output am getting and the line am talking about
[jsfeedle link](https://jsfiddle.net/camindo/18mda54x/4/)

Comment: Have you tried different values for `style.right` and `style.bottom`, instead of both using `percentage`?

Comment: i hadn't, now that I have tried it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I realize that I had been using the same value for the bottom and right.
I slightly changed my code to this and it works as expected.

```
function createDiv(){
    for(i=0;i<=60;i++){
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div')
        newdiv.classList = `name${i}`
        // const newproduct = document.querySelector(`.name${i}`)

        const right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        const left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        const distance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)
        const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        const c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)

        const d = Math.random().toFixed(1)
        


        newdiv.style.right = `${right}%`
        newdiv.style.borderRadius = '50%'
        newdiv.style.bottom = `${left}%`
        newdiv.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(${a},${b},${c},${d})`;
        newdiv.style.width = `${distance}px`
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute'
        newdiv.style.height = `${distance}px`

        backgroundColor.append(newdiv)
        console.log(newdiv)
    }
}

createDiv()
```